# xlswriter dropdown list Excel error

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

to apply data validation for all rows in a specific column the following sequence is use :

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('data_validate2.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

status_col_loc=1
for row in range(1,50000):
    worksheet.data_validation(xlsxwriter.utility.xl_rowcol_to_cell(row,status_col_loc) ,{'validate':'list' ,'source': ['Closed','Pending','Redirected']})
workbook.close()
```

this approach works perfectly when the number of rows applied is less than 50K.Beyond that it corrupts the excel file

[image: Excel xml error]

Is there any way to apply validation to more that 100K rows without corrupting the excel file ?

Answer (score 2):

Excel has an undocumented limit of 60,000 unique non-contiguous data validations per worksheet.

Excel does support > 60,000 non-unique, non-contiguous data validations by using an optimisation for duplicate validations (after 60,000).

<strike>However, XlsxWriter doesn't support this optimization so you will have to limit the data validations in your worksheet to 60,000.</strike>

**Update from 2023**: The Excel limit of 60,000 unique non-contiguous data validations per worksheet still exists. However, for the secondary case of 60,000 non-unique, non-contiguous data validations it is now possible to work around this using the `multi_range` feature of `worksheet.data_validation()`.

Comment: Thanks, I see that this request has been raised in the past github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/issues/240 . is this possible to have this as a feature request? If the Excel application permits this feature, is there a particular reason why XlsxWriter limits this?

Comment: There main reasons that this issue isn't fixed is that it isn't commonly encountered (this is only the second report of it that I've had) and the fix is labourious and requires a lot of tests for edge cases.

Comment: In this instance I have to resort to openpyxl  for this feature otherwise I would always go with xlswriter.

Comment: @DACW hi there, I wonder how did you resolve it using openpyxl?

Comment: @TrungHieuNguyen See my update above in relation to XlsxWriter.

Comment: @jmcnamara, I'm using openpyxl, and it seems that with the question of DACW, it should be easier since the source of data_validation is a fixed list. Because openpyxl supports adding a single validation to a range of cells. See the example from: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/validation.html