# xlsxwriter corrupts file after applying data validation on more than 71215 rows

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I've recently jumped from VBA to python trying to improve the reporting on my company so I am a bit new in python.

What my program tries to do is after consolidating various CSV files in one dataframe, applying datavalidation in form of a dropdown list with xlsxwriter.

I was getting a corrupted file everytime after the process was done and so, the data validation was gone.

I've been playing with the limits to find out it can only apply data validation for 71215 rows of data, after that the file becomes corrupt.

Because this only happens with large data, I can't provide an example of dataframe but it would be like:

```
df = pd.read_csv(fichero, sep=";", dtype={
                                            "Dirección": "string",
                                            "Territorio": "string", 
                                            "DNI": "string", 
                                            "Agente": "string",
                                            "CentroACC": "string",
                                            "ModoACC": "string",
                                            "Fecha": "string",
                                            "Presentes": "string",
                                            "Contratados": "string",
                                            "Modo Planificación": "string",
                                            }
                )
```

Here is the code which is implementing the data validation. Works fine, won't raise any error, but the result is a corrupted xlsx file.

```
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter as xl
import numpy as np
import time
from diccionarios import diccionarioHabilidadesAgente as dh
def cargaListaHabilidades(df, Fecha):
    df = df.copy();
    df['Habilidades Vigentes'] = np.where((df['INICIO'] <= Fecha) & (Fecha <=  df['FIN']), 1, 0)   
    df = df.loc[df['Habilidades Vigentes']==1]
    return df['Campaña'].tolist()
def main(df, rutaficheros):
    inicio = time.perf_counter()
    dfHabilidades = pd.read_csv(rutaficheros + 'Habilidades.csv', sep=";")
    diccionarioHabilidades = dh(dfHabilidades)
    fin1 = time.perf_counter()
    print('diccionario habilidades generado en: ', fin1 - inicio, ' segundos.')
    del(dfHabilidades)
    fichero = rutaficheros + 'Consolidado_ACC.xlsx'    
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(fichero, engine='xlsxwriter') 
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Descarga ACC')
    workbook  = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets['Descarga ACC']
    fin2 = time.perf_counter()
    print('Excel generado en: ', fin2 - fin1, ' segundos.')
    for fila in range(0, 71214):#len(df)):
        Agente = df.iloc[fila]['DNI']
        Fecha = df.iloc[fila]['Fecha']
        if Agente in diccionarioHabilidades:
            if Fecha in diccionarioHabilidades[Agente]:
                lista = diccionarioHabilidades[Agente][Fecha]
                worksheet.data_validation('K' + str(fila + 2), {'validate': 'list',
                                            'source': lista})  
    fin3 = time.perf_counter()
    print('validación aplicada en: ', fin3 - fin2)                          
    workbook.close()
    print('guardado el fichero en: ', time.perf_counter() - fin3, ' segundos.')
    return
```

Like this the code works because I manually input 71214 on the loop, but the total number of rows is like 100k.

I've wanted to ask if someone would know why is the reason of this before doing the less pretty process of spliting the df in 2 and generate 2 separated files.

Edit:

- Excel can handle way more data validations (it was done by VBA).
- Each data validation needs to be applied on it's own because people have different set of skills for each day of the month.

Comment: Two questions. Q1. Is this an Excel limitation on the number of data validations supported in a worksheet? For example can you manually add data validations past the 71214 limit in Excel? Q2. Do you actually have 70k different data validations or could you apply a small number of data validations to bigger ranges.

Comment: @jmcnamara First question, no, there is no Excel limitation(this was being done by VBA but takes like 20 times longer). Every Agent in this table has it's own skills so I need to apply datavalidation to each individual separately because two people could have the same skills but for one ends on the middle of the month and the other one doesn't. The dictionary cares for that and applies the skills for each person and day of the month. Will update the question with this.

Comment: What does `stop iterating` mean? Do you get an error? Is the CPU pegged at 100% for a long time? Or is it 0?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  I mean the `len(df)`is like 100k but I manually put 71214 which is 71215 rows. The code works perfectly, it won't give any problem during execution.

Comment: So what's the problem? Apart from the idea of using a 100K-row sheet for user input. Excel can handle 1M rows but *humans* can't. Is that sheet used as a "database" perhaps?

Comment: Also, what are the actual validation rules? You could add extra data and formulas in hidden columns and have the validation check the contents/results of those columns. Instead of 100K different validations you'd have a single one checking a few conditions stored in the same row

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the problem is that past the 71215 rows, If the xlsxwriter applies another data validation in row 71216 it returns a corrupted file which then I open, press yes to the error message and the whole sheet is without data validation, losing the dropdown lists that this bit of code tries to apply.

Comment: Could you share some of the corrupt and non-corrupt (VBA?) file via the XlsxWriter GitHub issues or elsewhere? XlsxWriter writes all data validations in the same way so there isn't any reason that validations beyond 70k would be corrupt. It is most likely that there is some undocumented internal limit in Excel. I have seen instances like this in the past. If it works with VBA then there must be some way to handle that limit or Excel is grouping similar contiguous ranges together. P.S. I am the author of XlsxWriter.

Comment: Actually you can hold off on the files. I was able to reproduce it with a simple test case. I am investigating.

Comment: @jmcnamara thank you for the update! I read a similar thread where you were telling that xlsxwriter has some 60k individual datavalidations limit, don't know if it's that but I'm at 71215 distinc validations without error.

Comment: @jmcnamara actually tried out with openpyxl and the same result, but with even less rows... Thought I have a file with 103k rows filled with data validation in one column. So excel can handle it, at least when done by VBA.

Comment: From my testing I can see that there is an Excel limit on the number of unique data validations or the memory used by them. Excel avoids this by combining similar contiguous data validations into a single range or by storing multiple ranges for similar non-contiguous data validations. You could simulate the former approach by extending the range if the data validation is the same as the previous cell(s). The latter will take an extension to XlsxWriter. I'll write up a longer explanation and create a GitHub feature request over the weekend. P.S., do you have a link to the previous thread?

Comment: @jmcnamara thank you for your efforts. Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44114170/7558682)

Comment: @Damian I've added a feature request for a option that would help you work around this issue/limitation: https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/issues/874 Note, in the meantime you could probably workaround the issue by grouping similar contiguous data validations into a range like K3:K5 (although you should use the list syntax for this, rather than the string syntax).

Comment: Thank you @jmcnamara I'm using another approach, but as long as this limitation gets sorted, will try it again!